# Primitive propositions in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am a little confused over the exact meaning of a "primitive proposition". I understand what a proposition is (if $p, q \in L$ then $p \Rightarrow q \in L$).

But what is the exact difference between a "primitive proposition"and just any old proposition?

Comment: Can you give us a ref to the text are you using ?

Comment: Maybe [Atomic proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_sentence) vs "compound" propositions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in the fact that a primitive (or atomic) proposition's truth does not "depend" on that of any simpler proposition, that is, it can't be "broken down" to simpler stuff. It does not contain any logical connectives or quantifiers.